# Problem in adding a new line character in TextArea field using a formula

Tags: formula, long-text-area

I have a Text Area field, which I am updating using a formula from Process Builder. I want to add a new line and tried to do so using '\n' and '\r\n' but none of these work.

Here is the formula used:

[CampaignMember].Secondary_Status_2__c + '\r\n' + TEXT([CampaignMember].Status)

Comment: Is the text area a rich text area?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using `BR()` in your formula?

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#BR)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work even. If I use BR(), then it adds the string _BR_ENCODED_

Comment: Mentioning again that I am trying to update the field from Process Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Check this super hack out, it should fix your problem. https://automationchampion.com/2015/08/06/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-40-adding-a-line-break-in-process-builder-formula/#comment-3963

Comment: what a hack!  a custom label value of a line break wrapped by text and then the wrapped text removed by the `SUBSITUTE(..)`. I love it

Comment: Please don't limit your anwers to an URL only. Include the actual in your answer so that if the external source may go offline we do not lose the information. Mind still adding it to your answer ?

Comment: Yes please provide at least the broad strokes... my company is behind a firewall and I don't have access to blogs and personal sites like this one =/